# Finding the pdf of a transformation of these independent random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables, linear-transformations, independence, gamma-distribution

[image]

Hi, I am looking at the question above. We know that $f_X(x) = \lambda^nx^{n-1}e^{-\lambda x}/\Gamma(n)$ and $f_Y(y) = \lambda e^{-\lambda y}$.

We also know that the range for each of these pdfs are $x>0$ and $y>0$.

Now, after computing we get $f_{UV}(u,v) = \lambda^n(u-v)^{n-1}e^{-\lambda(u-v)}/\Gamma(n)\hspace{3mm} \cdot \hspace{3mm}  \lambda e^{-\lambda v} $

Now I have to find the pdf of U. I know I have to integrate that equation between the limits of $v=u$ and $v=0$ to find said pdf of U. But I am stuck on the integral. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Are we assuming that $n$ is a positive integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^u f_{UV}(u, v) \mathop{dv}
&= \lambda^{n+1} e^{-\lambda u} \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)} \int_0^u (u-v)^{n-1} \mathop{dv}
\\
&= \lambda^{n+1} e^{-\lambda u} \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)} \left[- \frac{1}{n}(u-v)^n\right]_{v=0}^u
\\
&= \lambda^{n+1} e^{-\lambda u} \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\cdot  \frac{1}{n} u^n.
\end{align}
Can you take it from here? Note $\Gamma(n) \cdot n = \Gamma(n+1)$.

Comment: I see! So U would have a $gamma(n+1,\lambda)$ distribution, correct?